# Return only rows under certain constraints in join

Tags: postgresql

I am using PostgreSQL 11.6 and I have two tables: a `parent` and a `child` table.  The `child` table is associated to the `parent` in that it has a `parent_id` column and a `parent` can have many `child` rows associated.  The `child` also has a `status` column that I'd like to filter on.

Here are my requirements.  I need to return all rows from the `parent` table where either:

- there is **NO** associated `child` row present
- there are `child` rows present but none of those rows have a value in their `status` column of `at_home`

E.x.

```
parent table
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
|  2 |
+----+
```

```
child table
+------------------------+
| id  parent_id   status |
+------------------------+
| 1   1       at_school  |
| 2   1       at_shop    |
| 3   1       at_home    |
+------------------------+
```

My query should return only the `parent` with an `id` of `2` since that `parent` doesn't have an associated `child` record.  The `parent` with an `id` of `1` should only been returned if none if it's present `child` records had an `at_home` status.  With my query below, it is currently still being returned (which is incorrect).

I'm trying a query like this right now but it's not working because I'm filtering on `child` where the `status` is != to `at_home`, but it still returns a `parent` record because rows `1` and `2` of the `child` records above match that condition:

```
SELECT parent.* FROM parent LEFT OUTER JOIN child ON child.parent_id = parent.id WHERE (child.id is NULL OR child.status != 'at_home')
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: There are two child rows for parent 1 where status <> 'at_home', so why shouldn't it be returned? Perhaps you could clarify your condition.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe yes, it is just a custom business requirement.  There can be multiple status's for  child rows present against a parent but as soon as a status exists with `at_home`, I don't want any parent rows to be returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM parent
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM child
                  WHERE child.parent_id = parent.id
                  AND child.status = 'at_home');
```

Comment: Nice!  Does this also return the parent when no child records are present for it?

Comment: Sure, because then there is also no child that satisfies the `NOT EXISTS` condition.